# How to put a string variable in JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I have a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"The Mets scored!\", \"action\": \"com.vipulk.acuv.UPDATE_STATUS\",\"ph\": ph }");
```

I have a string defined as:

```
     String ph="this is String";
```

Now when i receive this JSONObject on receiver side I have the value of "ph" as "ph". I want the value of original String ph. How to do it. Can JSONObject send extra strings with another method.

Pardon my limited knowledge about JSON, as I am using it just once so I am avoiding going deep. I have everything done except putting this string variable in JSONObject.

NOTE: I am working with PARSE push notifications and I've to send this object in a push notification (that i am able to do).

Comment: What do you mean by *I have the value of "ph" as "ph"* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify your JSONObject, you can use .put method (http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
data.put("ph", ph);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I wasn't sure about using .put method. As there wasn't any mention of putting a string value in the docs (none that I could find)

Comment: Why that didn't work for me?
`JSONObject Customer= new JSONObject();
            Customer.put("name",name);`

Comment: Is it just an error in the Android documentation that there is no mention of putting a String into a JSON object? https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject